# how to change a model safe attributes in yii

Tags: php, yii, model

I have a CActiveRecord model, and I need to change safe attributes list in that model.
I have defined the safeAttributes method inside my model, like the following :

```
public function safeAttributes()
{
    return array(
    'name, bio',
    );
}
```

the problem is 'bio' is not being considered in my safe attribute assign. I tried to dump the model safeAttributeNames attribute in my model, and what I've got was completely different from what safeAttributes should return.

Am I doing this in the right way ?

cheers,
Firas

Comment: If `bio` is not being considered in safe attribute assign, you can simply remove it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Yii 1.0.x then that is the correct way to do it.

If you are using Yii 1.1.x then it's changed. Have another read of the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/form.model).

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
        array('something', 'safe'),
        array('someOtherThing', 'unsafe'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Also if you want to define an attribute which is _safe_ only during registration you can add this rule `array('some_field', 'safe', 'on'=>'register')` and then instantiate the model (provided it's the User model) like this `$model=new User('register');`